# Any US deportation illegal immigrants statistics by presidents?

Tags: united-states, immigration, statistics, illegal-immigration

Different US presidents usually have different view on the question of adopting illegal immigrants. Some, for example D.Trump are generally opposing immigration, some, like current POTUS J.Biden, are welcoming it. So, I consider, that deportation rate should also respond it.

Is there are any statistics on deportated illegal immigrants in the 21st century?

Comment: Are you asking about legal immigration or illegal immigration? Those are very separate issues

Comment: @divibisan, illegal immigrants, I'll edit the question now

Comment: What do you mean by "adoption"? It's not like illegal immigrants apply and are accepted or deported. They are, by definition, outside the system. There definitely could are statistics for deportation rates, and I bet you could find statistics for the number of people who enter or remain in the country (after visa expiration) illegally. But I don't know what you mean by "adoption" rate

Comment: Hmm. Interesting. Let's then consider only deportations

Comment: A good answer would take into account how deportation rates are also dependent on arrival rates.

Comment: @EveryoneElse I suppose the relationship is weak.  Obviously everyone being deported has to have arrived at some point, but an increase in (for example) tourism from Europe, Canada, and Japan is probably going to have very little bearing on the deportation rate.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some resources, from a simple google search. No endorsement of the sources is implied.

https://www.dhs.gov/immigration-statistics/yearbook/2017/table39

https://www.cato.org/blog/deportation-rates-historical-perspective

https://www.pewresearch.org/fact-tank/2020/03/02/how-border-apprehensions-ice-arrests-and-deportations-have-changed-under-trump/

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged on stack exchange, both because they’re lazy (if you just copied links from a google search, what value is there in an answer) and because if the links break, then the answer will be useless. If you’re going to answer, please take the time to read your sources and summarize or at least comment on the key information.

Comment: @divibisan, I understand and agree, but would point out it's more of an answer (with actual sources) than anyone else bothered to give - i.e. currently the *only* answer. I invite you to edit and copy some of the data in there.

Comment: @PeteW in that case perhaps you should make the answer a community wiki.

Comment: how do you do that?